# Haskell parse error, for averaging program

Tags: haskell

I need to get the average, so input is stopped until user puts in a negative number and then the output is the average

```
  {
    getFloat :: IO Float
    getFloat = do line <- getLine
                    return (read line:: Float) 


    average :: IO Float
    average =  helper summ n
                    where
                    helper :: Float->Float->IO Float
                    helper summ n = do val<-getFloat
                                       if (val<0)
                                          then (return average)
                                          else ( do summ = summ + val
                                                    n = n+1
                                                    average= summ/n
                                                    average)
                                                         }
```

Comment: Please paste the error. Also, any question usually should contain at least one `?`

Comment: hs:46:54: parse error on input '='

Comment: how do i fix this parse error, and alogotihm to get the correct program

Comment: Your indentation in `getFloat` is broken. Is it the same in your file?

Answer (score 2):

It's better to separate pure and impure computations. I.e., `average` could be just `[a] -> b` without IO effects.

```
main = print =<< average `fmap` go []
  where
    go :: [Int] -> IO [Int]
    go xs = do
      x <- (read :: String -> Int) `fmap` getLine
      if x < 0 then return (x : xs) else go (x : xs)

    average :: [Int] -> Float
    average xs = (fromIntegral $ sum xs) / (fromIntegral $ length xs)
```

---

This is not the best solution, by the way:

- [`readLn :: Read a => IO a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO.html#v%3areadLn)
- average value could be get easier without traversing a `List` twice

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
main = do (s,n) <- getnums
          putStrLn $ show $ s / (fromIntegral n)

getnums :: IO (Float, Int)
getnums = go 0.0 0
  where go s n = do line <- getLine
                    let f = read line :: Float
                    if f < 0 then return (s,n)
                             else go (s+f) (n+1)
```

Comment: `getLine >>= \line -> return $ read line` is the same as `read <$> getLine` which is the same as `readLn`. And you don't need an explicit type signature for `read` if you do something with the result that fixes its type.

Comment: True. I think the OP's real problem was how to perform looping in a monadic computation, so I tried to make my code as similar to the original.